# How to use dynamically generated javascript in an SRC attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some Javascript, which generates other Javascript code and puts it in a string:

```
var my_string = "alert('Hello World!');";
```

(This is a gross oversimplicication of how I am actually getting a string that contains JS code, but needless to say, via a process that is too long to describe, I end up with one - this isn't something I can change.)

What I want to do is figure out a way to use the Javascript that's contained in that string in the SRC attribute of a new SCRIPT tag that I'm going to write to the document head. For reasons I can't explain, I can't write it inline.

I tried using HTML5 local storage to do this, like so:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem('hello', my_string);

// Access
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
s.setAttribute("src", "javascript:localStorage.getItem('hello')");
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

But apparently it just doesn't work that way. Can't use IDBObjectStore for the same reason.

I also looked into using the HTML5 FileSystem API, which would do exactly what I need to solve this problem, but that only works in Chrome. I need my code to work in Firefox.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Even though I wrote an answer already, I'm not sure if I full understand the problem. Why do you think you need a `script` tag?

Answer (score 1):

The `src` attribute has to reference a file that is loaded and evaluated as JavaScript. If you want to evaluate a string as JavaScript, just use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

```
eval("localStorage.getItem('hello')");
```

Of course you should only do this if the input is trustworthy. Otherwise this is a big security hole.

---

In case you really want to use a script tag, you have to set the code as *content* of the element:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.text = "localStorage.getItem('hello')";
document.head.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a difference between .text and .innerHTML, in this case? Or is it essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. Normally when you use `.innerHTML`, the HTML parser should kick in, which could lead to problems if your source code somehow contains valid HTML. So that's why I thought `.text` is a safer option here.